# Contained menu to reveal stacked divs on click with transition

Tags: jquery, html, menu, z-index

Using technique in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hiimmike/kDYD9/), how do I get list items that point to stacked divs to bring linked div into focus (with a transition) upon click?

I'm looking to combine someone's jsfiddle that shows a transition on a static page each time a menu item is selected.

My example uses a toggle menu. Once opened, I'd like for the list item that is clicked to reveal the div it points to along with a transition. My CSS layout is fine and I know the divs are stacked because when I select the bottom div and give it a display of none, the div box below it (colored in green) is revealed.

Here's a look at my code:

```
<div id="maincontainer">
<nav id="sidebar-flex">
  <div id="menu">  
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#content1">The Journey</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#content2">The Pain of Infertility</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>India's Growing Insustry</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Fertility Hights and Lows</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>The Income Gap</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>    
</nav>
<div id="contentwrap">

    <div id="header-flex"> <span id="button-flex"></span></div>
      <div id="content1">
            <h1>Amazingly simple off canvas navigation</h1>

            <h2>with Flexbox & toogleClass</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content2">
            <h1>Amazingly simple off canvas navigation</h1>

            <h2>with Flexbox & toogleClass</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my (forked and modified) jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hiimmike/RG7c2/2/

And here's a link to the jsfiddle (I forked) with the script I'd like to apply to my layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/hiimmike/kDYD9/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar I've added my question in the first line of this post. Thanks for flagging that for me.